# Problems with AucTeX and Emacs24

Tags: emacs, auctex

I download AucTeX from ELPA and put nothing in my `.emacs` file. However, the commands `auctex` and `preview-latex` do not seem to be there (when I try `M-x auctex` or `M-x preview-latex`, Emacs cannot find them).

When I try to put [the load commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Loading-the-package.html#Loading-the-package) in my `.emacs` file, I get errors:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "auctex.el")
  load("auctex.el" nil t t)
```

If I look in my emacs elpa directory, `auctex.el` does not seem to be present:

```
~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.86$ ls auctex*
auctex-autoloads.el  auctex.info  auctex.info-1  auctex.info-2  auctex-pkg.el  auctex-pkg.elc
```

When I open a basic, correctly formatted, `.tex` file and try to run preview-buffer (`M-x preview-buffer`), the following happens:

> Cache preamble? (y or n) y
>
> Type C-c C-l to display results of compilation.

So I do, at which point I get this garbage:

```
! Preview: Snippet 1 started.
<-><->
      
l.11 $
      a\in S$
Preview: Tightpage -32891 -32891 32891 32891
! Preview: Snippet 1 ended.(537395+30747x1884782).
<-><->
      
l.11 $a\in S$
             
[1] )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on _region_.dvi (1 page, 1640 bytes).
Transcript written on _region_.log.

Preview-LaTeX exited as expected with code 1 at Mon Mar 11 01:40:34
Running `Preview-DviPS' with ``dvips -Pwww _region_.dvi -o _region_.prv/tmp11354CiZ/preview.ps''
This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2013.03.11:0140' -> _region_.prv/tmp11354CiZ/preview.ps
</usr/share/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/special.pro>. 
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb>[1] 

Preview-DviPS finished at Mon Mar 11 01:40:34
Running `Preview-Ghostscript' with ``gs -dOutputFile\=\(_region_.prv/tmp11354CiZ/pr1-\%d.png\) -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=png16m -r102.4x102.669''

Preview-Ghostscript finished at Mon Mar 11 01:40:34
```

I'm not sure what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Go to scratch, paste in `(and (load "auctex.el" nil t t) (load "preview-latex.el" nil t t))` and enter `^J` with the cursor at the end of that form: what do you get?  If you get the result `t`, then both Elisp files are in your path.

Comment: 'Cannot open load file "auctex.el"' Let me rewrite the original post.

Comment: You need to fix the contents of the Emacs variable `load-path` so it includes directories that contain the missing `.el` sources.  Perhaps entering the form `(setq load-path (cons "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.86" load-path))` will fix your problem?

Comment: Nothing changed when I put the load-path instruction in my .emacs file. Like I said in the OP, that directory is missing auctex.el.

Comment: I have `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.86` in my `load-path` and I still have the same problem. Also, I do not see `auctex.el` or `preview-latex.el` in that directory...

Comment: @CharlesStewart have you tried emacs 24 elpa package loading (they changed everything:-)

Answer (score 7):

Don't try to mix elpa package loading with old style editing your startup file. Either you will confuse the package manager or the package manager will confuse you.

This came up in chat the other day

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=10035300#10035300

Following the thread there worked when I tried it.

The important bit is remove all existing references to auctex from your emacs then
do what it says [in the new manual for elpa installs of auctex](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Installation.html)

> Simply do M-x package-list-packages RET, mark the auctex package for
>   installation with i, and hit x to execute the installation procedure.
>   That’s all.